# How do I solve this jump puzzle at Snowy Peaks?

Tags: monster-sanctuary

I'm having trouble getting through this jump puzzle at Snowy Peaks.

I have to jump from here:
[image]

...to the ice platform at the upper left, and then to the other ice platform above and to the right of it.
[image]

Screenshot of location in map:
[image]

I'm having trouble getting to the first ice platform. It seems to almost instantly disintegrate when I am about to land on it. I've successfully jumped to the first platform once by being flown by my Spectral Eagle but have not made it to the second platform. I was not able to get back to the first platform again after multiple attempts. I was wondering if there is another Monster ability I need to use or a specific strategy on how to jump and get carried by my Monster.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need a Monster with a 'create an obstacle' explore ability to do this jump easily. In my case, I had Fungi, which has 'Summon Mushroom', an ability which allows it to create a mushroom obstacle.

[image]

I placed a mushroom obstacle at this location and I was able to do the jump in one try:
[image]